# CSS flex layout - Cropped text & Missing right margin

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to use flex layout in simple image gallery (wip) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vmhLe.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.thumbPanel {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    border: 2px solid MidnightBlue;
    background-color: Gray;
}

.thumbAdminMenu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.thumbAdminButton {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;

    border: 2px solid MidnightBlue;
    font-size: 20pt;
}

.thumbList {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;

    border: 2px solid MidnightBlue;
    background-color: Gainsboro;
}

.thumbArea {
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 5px;

    background-color: LightGoldenRodYellow;
    border: 1px solid MidnightBlue;
}
.thumbArea:first-child,  {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.thumbArea:last-child {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="thumbPanel">
    <div class="thumbAdminMenu">
        <button class="thumbAdminButton">AddXXX</button>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbList">
        <div class="thumbArea"></div>
        <div class="thumbArea"></div>
        <div class="thumbArea"></div>
        <div class="thumbArea"></div>
        <div class="thumbArea"></div>
        <div class="thumbArea"></div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The result (browser window shrinked):

[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuIcQ.png

Why is the text AddXXX cropped?

Why is the right margin of right most yellow div missing? I'm setting it with `.thumbArea:last-child` rule.

Here's the playground: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vmhLe. There's an issue on codepen and jsfiddle with bottom horizontal scrollbar overflowing (at least for me in Chrome). But when viewing HTML file it displays fine. Also if you open developer console in Chrome it will display fine too.

Thank you.

Comment: Your first problem is an easy fix, add `flex:none` to `.thumbAdminMenu` to stop it from shrinking. As to the right margin...it's got me stumped on how to fix it. I even tried adding padding to the container instead.

Comment: @JonP, for the cropped text `flex: none` indeed helps. I've also reduced it just to `flex-shrink: 0`. (I thought I already tried). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the cropped text issue neither on Firefox nor Chromium.

You can fix the margin issue adding an `::after` pseudo-element for the wrapper:

```css
.thumbList:after {
  content: '';    /* Enabling the pseudo-element */
  min-width: 5px; /* Fake margin */
  height: 1px;    /* Anything but 0 */
}
```

```css
.thumbPanel {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid MidnightBlue;
  background-color: Gray;
}
.thumbAdminMenu {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.thumbAdminButton {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: 2px solid MidnightBlue;
  font-size: 20pt;
}
.thumbList {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid MidnightBlue;
  background-color: Gainsboro;
}
.thumbArea {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
  background-color: LightGoldenRodYellow;
  border: 1px solid MidnightBlue;
}
.thumbList:after {
  content: '';
  min-width: 5px;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbPanel">
  <div class="thumbAdminMenu">
    <button class="thumbAdminButton">AddXXX</button>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbList">
    <div class="thumbArea"></div>
    <div class="thumbArea"></div>
    <div class="thumbArea"></div>
    <div class="thumbArea"></div>
    <div class="thumbArea"></div>
    <div class="thumbArea"></div>
    <div class="thumbArea"></div>
    <div class="thumbArea"></div>
    <div class="thumbArea"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```